# Remake files older than 24 hours?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I wonder if there is a way to tell GNU `make` to remake a file older than, say, 24 hours.

I.e., something like `force`, but only if the target has been last updated over 24 hours ago.

Let's say I have a program which collects sensor data. I don't want to ping the sensors more often than every 24 hours.

Comment: Doe you mean: ... and *not* remake files that are newer?

Comment: @reinierpost: Please see edit. Is it more clear? Are you the downvoter?

Answer (score 1):

Keep a sentinel file around. Date it 24 hours in the past and use normal make dependencies. Recursive make. (All round yuk!)

```
.PHONY: poll
poll:
    touch -d yesterday sentinel
    ${MAKE} target

target: sentinel
    blah blah
    touch $@
```

Assumes gnu *touch*.